# How do i use the color mentioned in "app/color.xml" in "sdk/color.xml"?

Tags: android

I need to change the color from app to the library(SDK).
I need to use the color that is in color.xml file which is in app in the SDK.
The SDK has its own color.xml. So the changes made in color.xml file in app should apply to SDK as well.

app/color.xml

```
<resource>
 <color name="pop_up">#4fe40f</color>
</resource>
```

SDk/color.xml

```
<resource>
<color name="popup_color">?attr/pop_up</color>
</resource>
```

SDK/attrs.xml

```
<resources>
    <attr name="pop_up" format="reference|color"/>
</resources>
```

I have tried using ?attrs/color_name and parent/child styles, not able to override the color in SDK.

Expected Result ::

app/color.xml

```
<resource>
 <color name="pop_up">#4fe40f</color>
</resource>
```

SDk/color.xml

```
<resource>
<color name="popup_color">@color/pop_up</color> // color "pop_up" should come from app and apply here.
</resource>
```

Answer (score 0):

NO need to read the value from app/color.xml it will directly override if the color with the same color name is present in SDK/color.xml

app/color.xml

```
<resource>
 <color name="pop_up">#4fe40f</color>
</resource>
```

SDk/color.xml

```
<resource>
<color name="pop_up">#64646585</color> // #4fe40f is override
</resource>
```

Answer (score 0):

Solution:

app/color.xml

`<resource>
 <color name="pop_up">#4fe40f</color>
</resource>`

SDK/color.xml

`<resource>
<color name="pop_up">"#000000"</color>
</resource>`

Resource file of project will always override the resource file of sdk.
Define a parameter name in sdk and it will use value from project if same parameter name exists in main project.

So your solution is to declare a color with name pop_up in sdk and same in project.

Comment: Thankyou @aman choudhary for your solution, I am also tried the same way.

Comment: No problem brother.